# JavaFX Images not showing when running Jar

Tags: java, javafx, jar, ant

Everything is perfect when building/running jar with the IDE however when I use ANT to build project no images show. They were defined using scene builder and document relative path.

e.g. "@../resources/pic.png"

I have tried everything I saw online but still nothing (I was working on it for 5hours). Any help would be appreciated as I am out of ideas.

Comment: `..` is not valid for a resource path.  If it worked in your IDE, that was a happy accident.  Use a path that is relative to the root of your project.  It is most likely supposed to be `@pic.png` or `@resources/pic.png`.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately.  @VGR

Comment: Make sure that the resources folder actually exists and that the folder has a pic.png file inside it. If you are trying to package the resources inside your jar then you need to check `build.xml` and make sure you are linking/packaging your resource file correctly. If you want more help then edit your question to include the contents of your ant `build.xml`. Additionally add some of your own debug code to check if the image exists before loading it, then you will know if that is the issue.